# update some attributes of an object and return the whole object

Tags: json, spring-data-jpa, crud

I am trying to update a Customer password having his email, and after my update i want the `ResponseEntity` to return the whole Customer Object after modification is done.

But I am having this error into postman:

```
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"error_description": [
    "could not execute batch; SQL [insert into tcustomer (authentication_uid, creation_date, attribute_uid, default_payment_method_uid, guid, last_edit_date, pref_bill_address_uid, pref_ship_address_uid, status, storecode, type, user_id, uidpk) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch"
]
```

I am passing a JSON with the the password and email:

```
{
    "password": "miam",
    "userId":   "ton.nya@yahoo.fr"
}
```

**here is the serviceImpl:**

```
    public CustomerDto updateCustomerPassword( String userId, String password) {
    CustomerAuthentication customerAuthentication = new CustomerAuthentication();
    customerAuthentication.setPassword(password);
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setAuthenticationUid(customerAuthentication);
    customer.setUserId(userId);
    Customer result = customerRepository.save(customer);
    return customerMapper.customerToCustomerDto(result);
}
```

**here is the ressource**

```
    @PutMapping(CUSTOMER_ENDPOINT)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "The Customer has been created", response = CustomerDto.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 204, message = "The Customer has been updated", response = CustomerDto.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Unexpected error")
})
@Timed
public ResponseEntity updateCustomer(final HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String  userId, String password)throws MethodArgumentNotValidException{

    log.debug("[CustomerResource] PUT {} Updating Customer", CUSTOMER_ENDPOINT);

    CustomerDto result = customerService.updateCustomerPassword(userId,password);

    log.debug("[CustomerResource] Customer ({}) Updated",result.getUidpk());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result,null, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

**Are there any other solution? Thanks.**

Comment: Did you have bankend code? The problem is probably  on saving in DB.

Comment: ya let me paste.

Comment: Could you show the part of SQL's Code `insert into tcustomer`?
Because the problem was on it.

Comment: am using the JpaRepository